# Open FindCornerSubPix algorithm

Tags: algorithm, opencv

Is there any papers that describe the algorithm of the FindCornerSubPix function in openCV? I cannot find any documentation which describes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe from the source code (for version 2.1) it is using the image gradients to optimise location...

```
cv.h:
997 /* Adjust corner position using some sort of gradient search */
998 CVAPI(void)  cvFindCornerSubPix( const CvArr* image, CvPoint2D32f* corners,
999                                  int count, CvSize win, CvSize zero_zone,
1000                                  CvTermCriteria  criteria );
```

The documentation for the function also describe this - particular the nature of the objective function used:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_feature_detection.html?highlight=findcornersubpix#cvFindCornerSubPix

More explicit details of the operation are found in the file cvcornersubpix.cpp. Looking at this it can be clearly seen that the function is calculating the derivatives of the search area and building a Hessian matrix...

In other words, as I understand it, a standard Conjugate gradient method!

Version 2.2 of OpenCV (the most up-to-date) does not appear to have this function anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It becomes more clear now, but in documentation (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/imgproc_feature_detection.html?highlight=findcornersubpix#cvFindCornerSubPix) there is a system of equation and I cannot understand how it was built.. And why there is "DI_pi", the gradient at point p_i, occuring two times?

Comment: From what I understand of the documentation, the reference to DI_pi*DI_pi^T (i.e. multiplied by its transpose) is simply describing the sum of gradients across the pixel neighbourhood of _q_ . This can be seen more clearly I think by having a quick look at the source code in cvcornersubpix.cpp again (lines 180 onwards) in which the calculation and summing of first and second order derivatives around the pixel neighbourhood and carried out - effectively building DI_pi (matrix _A_ in the code).